# Kerberos spring javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, kerberos, spring-security-kerberos

I am implementing kerberos Authentication in my existing java spring application.My unix team has provided me SPN, krb5.conf and keytab file. I am trying hard with below code and configuration but getting unable to obtain password from user exception as in attached logs below.

Can anybody correct me If I am doing something wrong or what could be going wrong? Let me know if you need more information on this.
It would be good if someone can tell, how to verify if kerberos configuration is correct or not?
Here is what I have tried. I am using:

- JDK 1.6
- spring-security-kerberos-core-1.0.0.M2.jar
- spring-security-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
- spring-security-config-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
- spring-security-web-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar

**My security-config.xml is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
           xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

<beans:bean class="com.ci.util.TrimmingPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <beans:property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true" />
        <beans:property name="locations">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>file:${install.home}/config/application.properties
                </beans:value>
                <beans:value>file:${install.home}/config/environment.properties
                </beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <http entry-point-ref="spnegoEntryPoint" auto-config="false">
        <intercept-url pattern="/selectBlacklisting*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_check*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
     <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />

     <custom-filter ref="spnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter" position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <form-login login-page="/selectBlacklisting.form" default-target-url="/" always-use-default-target="true"/>
   </http>

   <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
      <authentication-provider ref="kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider" />
      <authentication-provider ref="kerberosAuthenticationProvider"/>
   </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="spnegoEntryPoint"
  class="org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.web.SpnegoEntryPoint" />

 <beans:bean id="spnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter"
  class="org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.web.SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter">
  <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
 </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider"
  class="org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider">
  <beans:property name="ticketValidator">
   <beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator">
    <beans:property name="servicePrincipal" value="${servicePrincipal.url}"/>
    <beans:property name="keyTabLocation" value="${keyTabLocation.url}" />
    <beans:property name="debug" value="true"/>
   </beans:bean>
  </beans:property>
  <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="dummyUserDetailsService" />
 </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="kerberosAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.KerberosAuthenticationProvider">
  <beans:property name="kerberosClient">
   <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosClient">
    <beans:property name="debug" value="true" />
   </beans:bean>
  </beans:property>
  <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="dummyUserDetailsService" />
 </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.GlobalSunJaasKerberosConfig">
  <beans:property name="debug" value="true" />
  <beans:property name="krbConfLocation" value="${krbConfLocation.url}" />
 </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="dummyUserDetailsService" class="com.ci.manager.interceptor.DummyUserDetailService"/>

  </beans:beans>
```

**Properties values used in above security-config.xml:**

```
servicePrincipal.url=HTTP/xyzcard-sit1.systems.private@SYSTEMS.PRIVATE  
  keyTabLocation.url=file:/MY_APP_ITE3/appmanager/50.T0.17/config/xyzcard-sit1.keytab
  krbConfLocation.url=/etc/krb5/krb5.conf
```

**My DummyUserDetailService:**

```
public class DummyUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(DummyUserDetailService.class);
    public DummyUserDetailService(){
        LOGGER.info("DummyUserDetailService constructor called>>>>>>>>>");
    }


public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    LOGGER.info("loadUserByUsername method called>>>>>>>>>"+username);
    LOGGER.info("loadUserByUsername method called>AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList>>>>>>>>"+AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_USER"));
    return new User(username, "notUsed",true, true, true, true, AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_USER"));
}

}
```

**My web.xml is:**

```
    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
        version="2.4">

        <display-name>Customer Intelligence Management Tool</display-name>
        <distributable/>
        <filter>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <filter-class>
                org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
            </filter-class>    
        </filter>

        <filter-mapping>
              <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
              <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>
         <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/security-config.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>     
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener> 

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>app-manager</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>
                    /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml,
                    /WEB-INF/app-manager-servlet.xml
                </param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>app-manager</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.form</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <session-config>
            <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
        </session-config>

        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>

        <error-page>
            <error-code>500</error-code>
            <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/Error.jsp</location>
        </error-page>

        <error-page>
            <error-code>404</error-code>
            <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/FileNotFound.jsp</location>
        </error-page>
    </web-app>
```

**Application Logs showing exception:**

```
  015-04-20 13:07:42 ERROR  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader[ContextLoader.java:219(initWebApplicationContext)] - Context initialization failed
        org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'parent'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider' while setting bean property 'providers' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/security-config.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator#6e41b5' of type [org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator] while setting bean property 'ticketValidator'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator#6e41b5' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/security-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user

            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:281)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:125)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:562)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:871)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
            at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:272)
            at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:196)
            at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3764)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4216)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:760)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:740)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:544)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:825)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:714)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:490)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1138)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1022)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:736)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider' while setting bean property 'providers' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/security-config.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator#6e41b5' of type [org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator] while setting bean property 'ticketValidator'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator#6e41b5' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/security-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user

            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:150)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:109)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:274)
            ... 39 more
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider' while setting bean property 'providers' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/security-config.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator#6e41b5' of type [org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator] while setting bean property 'ticketValidator'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator#6e41b5' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/security-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user

            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:355)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:153)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
            at org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean.getObject(AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean.java:27)
            at org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean.getObject(AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean.java:20)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:143)
            ... 41 more
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/security-config.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator#6e41b5' of type [org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator] while setting bean property 'ticketValidator'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator#6e41b5' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/security-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user

            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:281)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:120)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
            ... 55 more
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator#6e41b5' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/security-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user

            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1403)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:270)
            ... 65 more
        Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user

            at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.promptForPass(Krb5LoginModule.java:789)
            at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:654)
            at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Krb5LoginModule.java:542)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:769)
            at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:186)
            at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$5.run(LoginContext.java:706)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokeCreatorPriv(LoginContext.java:703)
            at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:575)
            at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.afterPropertiesSet(SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.java:125)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1460)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1400)
            ... 68 more
```

**Server Logs:**

```
Apr 22, 2015 8:29:38 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
        INFO: validateJarFile(/MY_APP_ITE3/appmanager/50.T0.17/catalina_base/work/Catalina/localhost/app-manager/WEB-INF/lib/j2ee-1.4.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
        Debug is  true storeKey true useTicketCache false useKeyTab true doNotPrompt true ticketCache is null isInitiator false KeyTab is file:/MY_APP_ITE3/appmanager/50.T0.17/catalina_base/conf/xyzcard-sit1.keytab refreshKrb5Config is false principal is HTTP/xyzcard-sit1.systems.private@SYSTEMS.PRIVATE tryFirstPass is false useFirstPass is false storePass is false clearPass is false
        >>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): SYSTEMS.PRIVATE
        >>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): HTTP
        >>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): srv-xyzcard-sit1.systems.private
        >>> KeyTab: load() entry length: 88; type: 23
        Key for the principal HTTP/xyzcard-sit1.systems.private@SYSTEMS.PRIVATE not available in file:/MY_APP_ITE3/appmanager/50.T0.17/catalina_base/conf/xyzcard-sit1.keytab
          [Krb5LoginModule] authentication failed 
        Unable to obtain password from user

        Apr 22, 2015 8:29:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
```

Comment: I think question is worth answering . Why no answer? :-)

Comment: There are very few people that answer kerberos questions on SO and none of them seem to know Java Spring. Questions on this topic come up very often on the kerberos tag and they almost never get answered. My guess is that it's a DNS/krb5.conf file problem, the server is looking for a principal in the keytab that does not exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for responding. I have resolved the issue, problem was my keytab. My keytab file was not containing SPN which I was looking for. It was generated with wrong SPN. I tried with some dummy SPNs and found that I was getting same exception then asked team to validate or generate new keytab.

Comment: I used this article https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-kerberos-integration

Answer (score 4):

This may be due to property values not been resolved on the security-config. Can you hard code following and try again?

```
   <beans:property name="servicePrincipal" value="HTTP/xyzcard-sit1.systems.private@SYSTEMS.PRIVATE"/>
<beans:property name="keyTabLocation" value="file:YOUR KEY TAB LOCATION >>/mykey.keytabl" />
```

Your error has thrown from javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext's init method so it should be something about keytab file or service principle is not set properly.

Answer (score 0):

This one always drives me nuts cause it's kind of a generic/only semi-helpful error and it happens a lot.  I solved it this time by escaping the back slashes in the path to the krb5.conf file.