# Unable to connect spring boot with Secured Kerberos using jdbc template

Tags: java, spring-boot, kerberos, apache-phoenix, spring-security-kerberos

i am trying to connect kerberos cluster with springboot and facing some issue - 
here if my code -

```
package com.virginvoyages.nbx.phoenix.jdbc.config;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnProperty;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation;
/**
 * Spring JDBC Connection for Phoenix Hbase.
 * 
 * @author mokasara
 *
 */
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "deployment", havingValue = "ship")
@Configuration
public class PhoenixHbaseJDBCDatasourceShipConnection {

    @Value("${nbx.phoenix.hbase.ship.url}")
    private String nbxHbaseUrl;

    /**
     * Phoenix Datasource Connection Bean.
     * 
     * @return Datasource
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    @Bean
    public DataSource phoenixDataSource() throws IOException {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource1 = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", "src/main/resources/krb5.conf");
        org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration conf = new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration();
        conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");
        UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
        UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("hbase-dev@myhost.com","src/main/resources/hbase.headless.keytab");

        dataSource1.setUsername("username");
        dataSource1.setPassword("password"); 
        dataSource1.setDriverClassName("org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver");
        dataSource1.setUrl(nbxHbaseUrl);
        return dataSource1;
    }

    /**
     * Phoenix Hbase JDBC Template Bean.
     * 
     * @param dataSource
     *          - datasource
     * @return JdbcTemplate
     */
    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        return jdbcTemplate;
    }

}
```

i am getting below exception -

*
{"timestamp":"2019-12-04T17:56:23.118+05:30","version":1,"message":"Exception occurred in CalendarRecommendationDAOImpl method- getCalendarRecommendations ","logger_name":"com.virginvoyages.nbx.dao.impl.CalendarDaoSupport","thread_name":"http-nio-8438-exec-1","level":"ERROR","level_value":40000,"stack_trace":"org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ERROR 103 (08004): Unable to establish connection.\r\n\tat org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:81)\r\n\tat org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:371)\r\n\tat org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:452)\r\n\tat org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:462)\r\n\tat org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:473)\r\n\tat com.virginvoyages.nbx.dao.impl.CalendarDaoSupport.getCalendarRecommendations(CalendarDaoSupport.java:199)\r\n\tat com.virginvoyages.nbx.dao.impl.CalendarDaoSupport$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e665c50f.invoke()\r\n\tat org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)\r\n\tat com.virginvoyages.nbx.dao.impl.ARSInventoryHelper$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c7dbe61c.getCalendarRecommendations()\r\n\tat com.virginvoyages.nbx.assembly.impl.CalendarRecommendationAssemblyImpl.getCalendarRecommendation(CalendarRecommendationAssemblyImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat com.virginvoyages.nbx.assembly.impl.CalendarRecommendationAssemblyImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$bf2eae41.invoke()\r\n\tat org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:62)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:56)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:55)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)\r\n\tat com.virginvoyages.nbx.assembly.impl.CalendarRecommendationAssemblyImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6cb4e4b4.getCalendarRecommendation()\r\n\tat com.virginvoyages.nbx.calendar.CalendarRecommendationController.calendarRecommendationPost(CalendarRecommendationController.java:90)\r\n\tat com.virginvoyages.nbx.calendar.CalendarRecommendationController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d5e5fde5.invoke()\r\n\tat org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:56)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:55)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)\r\n\tat com.virginvoyages.nbx.calendar.CalendarRecommendationController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$25ffe737.calendarRecommendationPost()\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:665)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat com.virginvoyages.logging.LogFilter.doFilter(LogFilter.java:54)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat com.virginvoyages.api.OriginFilter.doFilter(OriginFilter.java:27)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat com.virginvoyages.logging.LogFilter.doFilter(LogFilter.java:54)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:117)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:106)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\r\nCaused by: java.sql.SQLException: ERROR 103 (08004): Unable to establish connection.\r\n\tat org.apache.phoenix.exception.SQLExceptionCode$Factory$1.newException(SQLExceptionCode.java:494)\r\n\tat org.apache.phoenix.exception.SQLExceptionInfo.buildException(SQLExceptionInfo.java:150)\r\n\tat org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixEmbeddedDriver$ConnectionInfo.normalize(PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.java:396)\r\n\tat org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.getConnectionQueryServices(PhoenixDriver.java:238)\r\n\tat org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.createConnection(PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.java:150)\r\n\tat org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.connect(PhoenixDriver.java:221)\r\n\tat java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)\r\n\tat java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)\r\n\tat org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:154)\r\n\tat org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:145)\r\n\tat org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:205)\r\n\tat org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:169)\r\n\tat org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:157)\r\n\tat org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:115)\r\n\tat org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:78)\r\n\t... 145 common frames omitted\r\nCaused by: java.io.IOException: Login failure for 2181/hbase-secure from keytab nbx.service@VIRGINVOYAGES.QA.DEV: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user\n\r\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(UserGroupInformation.java:979)\r\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.login(SecurityUtil.java:246)\r\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.User$SecureHadoopUser.login(User.java:420)\r\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.User.login(User.java:258)\r\n\tat org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixEmbeddedDriver$ConnectionInfo.normalize(PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.java:387)\r\n\t... 157 common frames omitted\r\nCaused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user\n\r\n\tat com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.promptForPass(Krb5LoginModule.java:897)\r\n\tat com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:760)\r\n\tat com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Krb5LoginModule.java:617)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\r\n\tat javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:755)\r\n\tat javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:195)\r\n\tat javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:682)\r\n\tat javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:680)\r\n\tat java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)\r\n\tat javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)\r\n\tat javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587)\r\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(UserGroupInformation.java:970)\r\n\t... 161 common frames omitted\r\n","clientID":"f0f4b93c-56a1-11e9-80d8-0a1a4261e962","correlationId":"bcf4dfc6-68ff-42eb-abed-d93ddcf76631","componentName":"recommendation-api","componentVersion":"0.0.1"}*

Comment: url i am using  is -
nbxHbaseUrl - jdbc:phoenix:ipaddress:2181/hbase-secure:hbase-dev@myhost.com:/src/main/resources/nbxservice.keytab

Comment: Either your keytab can not be located or it contains unexpected entries. Have you checked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29844339/kerberos-spring-javax-security-auth-login-loginexception-unable-to-obtain-passw